# How to use REST with Node.js and AngularJS being on different port?

Tags: javascript, apache, node.js, rest, angularjs

I am trying to understand the cooperation of Angular and Node.js on the backend. I can't figure out however, how to use REST for data transfer between the two.

I have:

1. Node.js backend running on port `8000`, responding to various GET and POST requests (via cURL).
2. Angular frontend is loaded through Apache, running on port `80`.

Naturally, the JavaScript console identifies it as `not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

How is this commonly solved? Am I doing it wrong? Should I not run the frontend through Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve it is using [Cross-origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Browser support is decent as well.

Comment: There isn't any cleaner way how to do it? There must be tons of pages using Ang + Node, don't tell me they're doing it this way :-O

Comment: You can proxy both applications through the same proxy, with different contexts instead.

Comment: Got it working with http://backbonetutorials.com/cross-domain-sessions/ thanks for pointing out, how to do it!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using **cors**

`npm install cors`

```
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://example.com'
}));
```

http://example.com is your application origin/domain at front-end side.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Node.js API server

```
server.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        return res.send(200);
    }
    next();
});
```